# ODE Solution $y''(x) = y^4(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, fundamental-solution

Is it possible to analytically calculate the ODE $y''(x) = y^4(x)$? It's easy to see that $y \equiv 0$, but is there another non-trivial solution to this problem?

If not, is there any software to help me with this problem?

Comment: multiply both sides by y' and integrate.

Comment: The first guess one should try is powers of $x$. A solution is $y(x)=cx^{-2/3}$, where $c$ is a suitable constant (if I am not wrong, c is the cubic root of 10/9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can immediately integrate once by multiplying by $y':$
\begin{align*}
y''&=y^4\\
y''y'&=y^4y'\\
\frac{(y')^2}{2}&=\frac{y^5}{5}+C_1\\
y'&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2y^5}{5}+2C_1}\\
\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2y^5}{5}+2C_1}}&=\pm(x+C_2).
\end{align*}
Now the integral on the LHS you can write in terms of hypergeometric functions as follows:
$$\frac{y\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2y^5}{5C_1}}\;\;_2F_1\!\!\left(\dfrac{1}{5},\dfrac{1}{2};\dfrac{6}{5};-\dfrac{2y^5}{5C_1}\right)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2y^5}{5}+C_1}}=\pm(x+C_2).$$
This is basically solved for $x.$ I highly doubt it's possible to solve for $y.$